# Do you get extra sticker book pages?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

Maybe I'm being impatient, but are you able to get additional pages for your sticker book?  I'm not very far in but I'm really overburdened with stickers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you progress through the story, you will get extra album pages for Stickers.

You can get a 3rd album page in World 1-3, as a 4th in World 1-6.  As you progress through the game, you will get even more pages.

But don't be afraid about **using** those stickers.  Stickers are ridiculously bountiful in this game.

(The extra Album pages do not affect Scraps or Things - your album will naturally expand to contain whatever Scraps / Things you have.)

Comment: Also, coins are *even more* bountiful so you can easily buy a ton of stickers to fill up the album, if you get low.

Answer (score 1):

You do get more pages as the game progresses, such as when you beat some bosses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you get them whenever you get a royal sticker, and also, you get one rather early in the game, right before fighting Kamek for the first time. (I think that's where you get your first one)

Comment: These are all covered in KatieK's answer. So unfortunately this answer adds absolutely nothing.